# cython pass by value situation

Tags: cython, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I have met an interesting case regarding cython pass by value.
The code is written in jupyter notebook:

```
%%cython -a
#cython: language_level = 3
#distutils: language = c++
from libcpp.map cimport map
from libcpp.string cimport string
cdef fun( map[ string, double ] a ):
    a[ b'H' ] = 10

cdef map[ string, double ] a
a[ b'H' ] = 0
fun( a )
print( a[ b'H' ] )
```

The return value is still 0

If we write it in python:

```
def fun( a ):
   a[ 'a' ] = 10
a = { 'a' : 5 }
fun( a )
print( a[ 'a' ] )
```

The answer will be 10

Can some experts explain why cython and python show different behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass by reference in C++ or a C++-objects in Cython you should pass it by reference, i.e. the signature of the function `fun` should be

```
cdef fun( map[ string, double ] &a ):
     ...
```

All Python-objects are pointers of type `PyObject *` and signature

```
def fun(object a):
   ...
```

is approximately translated to

```
PyObject *fun(PyObject *a){
      ...
}
```

i.e. arguments are passed as pointers, which corresponds to C++'s-references in pure C.